What does "throughout your generations" mean with respect to Mosaic Law?
What is the phrase “throughout your generations” referring to the Mosaic Law?  For example,

And God saith unto Abraham, `And thou dost keep My covenant, thou and thy seed after thee, to their generations; this [is] My covenant which ye keep between Me and you, and between thy seed after thee: Every male of you [is] to be circumcised” (Genesis 17:9-10, YLT)


"And a son of eight days is circumcised by you; every male to your generations, born in the house, or bought with money from any son of a stranger, who is not of thy seed;” (Genesis 17:12, YLT).


”... and they have made for themselves fringes on the skirts of their garments, to their generations, ...” (Numbers 15:38, YLT)

The word translated as “to” is the Hebrew preposition לְ (lə), which could mean “to,” “for,” or “of.”

The question needs to explain what the 'contradiction' is. Young's Literal translates all three passages as 'to their/your generations'. Is that what you are quoting ? (It's a good idea to reference your sources.) I haven't yet grasped the point of the question. Also, the header should be a question, not a statement.

There are several interpretations on the significance of Mosaic Laws in NT based on what Jesus and other NT authors say about it.  See the 1996 book Five Views on Law and Gospel.  For this question, you need to establish the contradiction by citing one of those interpretation, so that the group which holds to that interpretation and then explain to you how they resolve the contradiction.

If you just want exegesis, we can migrate the question to the hermenutics site, but we'd want to remove the part about confusion for early christians since that's somewhat polemical.  Please edit in a viewpoint so we can concentrate of what interpretation you're looking for

As you said they can be translated as "for" as in "for (the sake of) your generations" so strictly speaking it doesn't say that.  It is interesting that in both the case of olam and l-generations the plain meaning is forever but it can be translated as something else, whereas in any other language they would just mean what they appear to mean.  But even if it did say that, it doesn't really matter at this point (see https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/can-rabbinic-judaism-be-proven-false-apart-from-any-reference-to-christianity)

The Title question and the question at the end of the Body are completely different. Decide which question you want answered and get rid of the other or this item can't be reopened.

There are some other similar references of the covenant being eternal, forever.
The Jews use the references of the covenant of Moses being eternal as evidence against the Christ and his new covenant, which serves as a stumbling block or veil of Moses on their eyes, just like the letters of Paul serve as stumbling block for the "Christians" (2Pet 3:16).

Deut 29:29  “The secret things belong to the LORD our God, but the things that are revealed belong to us and to our children forever, that we may do all the words of this law.

These commands didn't prove to be hurdles when they realized the deeper truths, beyond the written things. Moreover, there are also interpretations or doctrines among the Jews that makes it clear that the law will end after the Messianic era, aka the age to come or the resurrection, where pigs will become kosher. The Rama Mipano (Asarah Mamaros Chikor Hadin 4:13) explains that Hashem will make the pig chew its cud, thereby making it kosher. The spiritual meaning behind this is that gentiles which represent pigs will become clean, the law of separation from gentiles or the law of Moses will cease in the coming of the Messiah.
Therefore, the covenant references stating that it is meant to be eternal are referring to the spirit of the law of God (Ps 119), rather than the outward regulations of the Moses law covenant.

Moreover, there are also interpretations or doctrines among the Jews that makes it clear that the law will end after the Messianic era as your link explains 1. These are minority opinions 2. The minority opinion applies in the period after the bodily resurrection of the righteous, which hasn’t occurred

You're right. However, that was just speculations of the theologians who did not know the age to come cane mean the Messianic rule or era on earth before the final resurrection, in light of the 2 arrivals of Messiah. He has resurrected being the first fruit of resurrection as the jewish disciples of Christ taught.

Only in Christianity are the statutes of the ceremonial law permanently established (as these words ‘throughout your generations’ command). They were symbolic of his priesthood that lasts forever and they were never practiced again shortly after his death. They have literally ceased in fact.
The Dictionary of Classical Hebrew Vol. 2 (1995, ed. by David J. A. Clines) has the following phrase (and its related verses) under the entry for דּוֹר ("generation"):

<COLL> [miscellaneous collocations] ‎חֻקַּ֥תעוֹלָ֖םלְדֹרֹ֣תֵיכֶ֔ם a perpetual statute throughout your generations, and vars [variants]. Ex 12:14,17; 27:31; 30:21; Lv 3:17; 6:11; 7:36; 10:9; 17:7;
23:14,21,31,41; 24:3; Nm 10:8; 15:15; 18:23; 35:29; ...

These perpetual statutes include: the Passover, the candlestick always burning in the tabernacle, the use of the bronze basin from washing hands and feet by the Aaronic priesthood, burning the fat of the sacrifices for the Lord, the Aaronic priesthood having the right to eat part of the grain offering, if anyone kills an animal in the camp or outside they must bring it to the tabernacle for a sacrifice, each harvest to sacrifice first fruits and also a spotless lamb, dwelling in booths for seven days as part of the feast of booths, when gathering to assemble the priesthood were to blow two silver trumpets, some rules around offering different grain or drink offerings whenever a animal was sacrificed for whatever reason, etc, etc
Numbers 15 on its own means that any animal sacrifice covering nearly all the ceremonial statues of the Aaronic priesthood should never be modified. The "throughout your generations" is emphasizing the unalterable nature of the legal ceremonies under that Priesthood.
This means that only by a change of the priesthood can any change be made. The author of Hebrews picks up on this important point because David prophesied of a new order of a Priesthood that was greater than Abraham (Psalm 100:4):

The LORD has sworn and will not change his mind: “You are a priest forever, in the order of Melchizedek.”

This was understood to be Messianic by some Rabbis prior to Christ (though it would not matter if it was not):

Ps. 110 is throughout applied to the Messiah. To begin with, it evidently underlies the Targumic rendering of ver. 4. Similarly, it is propounded in the Midr. on Ps. 2 (although there the chief application of it is to Abraham). But in the Midrash on Ps 18:36 (35 in our A.V.), Ps. 110 verse 1, ‘Sit thou at My right hand’ is specifically applied to the Messiah, while Abraham is said to be seated at the left.
From The Life and Times of Jesus the Messiah by Alfred Edersheim (1896), Appendix 9 (List of Old Testament Passages Messianically Applied in Ancient Rabbinic Writings)

So the Apostle (or the writer of Hebrews) argues in Heb 7:11-19 (NIV):

If perfection could have been attained through the Levitical priesthood—and indeed the law given to the people established that priesthood—why was there still need for another priest to come, one in the order of Melchizedek, not in the order of Aaron? For when the priesthood is changed, the law must be changed also. He of whom these things are said belonged to a different tribe, and no one from that tribe has ever served at the altar. For it is clear that our Lord descended from Judah, and in regard to that tribe Moses said nothing about priests. And what we have said is even more clear if another priest like Melchizedek appears, one who has become a priest not on the basis of a regulation as to his ancestry but on the basis of the power of an indestructible life. For it is declared: “You are a priest forever, in the order of Melchizedek.”  The former regulation is set aside because it was weak and useless (for the law made nothing perfect), and a better hope is introduced, by which we draw near to God.

Therefore until the Priesthood obtains a true eternal everlasting fulfillment of what the first priesthood symbolized, those statutes were not optional, ever, no matter the feigned excuse.
This permanent nature of the animal sacrificial system and constant shedding of blood to make atonement that became eternal is the fullest sense in Christ dying on a tree, make the modern Jew absolutely condemned by what they may claim as their heritage being that none of them follow these today.
Jews no longer followed the animal sacrificial system since shortly after the death and resurrection of their Messiah. In the destruction of their city they also lost the genealogical records that a Messiah could trace lineage directly to King David. This means that there can never be a Messiah other than the one believed by those early Jews. The sad history is that they both abandoned their own priesthood and did not received the new priesthood in which the old was eternally established. However it should be noted that before Christ returns at the end of history, it is belived by many that the nation of Israel will not be abandoned but will become identified as a Christian nation (Rom 11:25-32).
